# Проблема С ИИ в крестиках-ноликах

Tags: c++

Я делаю крестики-нолики на С++ с использованием алгоритма альфа-бета отсечения , столкнулся с проблемой когда бот делает не выгодные ходы (вместо того что бы заблокировать игрока он продолжает выстраивать свою комбинацию),буду благодарен если кто-то сможет указать на ошибку , заранее спасибо.(также стоит упомянуть , что игра делаеться для разного размера поля ,плюс должно соблюдаться условие : Еcли поле равно размеру 5 на 5 или меньше , то количество фигур для победы 3 , в остальных случаях 5)
Вот основной код ИИ:

```
int evaluate() {

    int player_two_count = 0;
    int computer_two_count = 0;
    int player_three_count = 0;
    int computer_three_count = 0;
    int player_four_count = 0;
    int computer_four_count = 0;

    // перевірка по рялкам
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int player_count = 0;
        int computer_count = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            if(board[i][j] == player) {
                player_count++;
            } else if(board[i][j] == computer) {
                computer_count++;
            }
        }
        if(player_count == 2) {
            player_two_count++;
        } else if(player_count == 3) {
            player_three_count++;
        } else if(player_count == 4) {
            player_four_count++;
        }
        if(computer_count == 2) {
            computer_two_count++;
        } else if(computer_count == 3) {
            computer_three_count++;
        } else if(computer_count == 4) {
            computer_four_count++;
        }
    }

    // Перевірка по солбцям
    for(int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        int player_count = 0;
        int computer_count = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if(board[i][j] == player) {
                player_count++;
            } else if(board[i][j] == computer) {
                computer_count++;
            }
        }
        if(player_count == 2) {
            player_two_count++;
        } else if(player_count == 3) {
            player_three_count++;
        } else if(player_count == 4) {
            player_four_count++;
        }
        if(computer_count == 2) {
            computer_two_count++;
        } else if(computer_count == 3) {
            computer_three_count++;
        } else if(computer_count == 4) {
            computer_four_count++;
        }
    }

    // перевірка по діагоналям
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            if(board[i][j] == player) {

                int count = 0;
                int k = 0;
                while(i + k < n && j + k < m && board[i + k][j + k] == player) {
                    count++;
                    k++;
                }
                if(count == 2) {
                    player_two_count++;
                } else if(count == 3) {
                    player_three_count++;
                } else if(count == 4) {
                    player_four_count++;
                }

                count = 0;
                k = 0;
                while(i + k < n && j - k >= 0 && board[i + k][j - k] == player) {
                    count++;
                    k++;
                }
                if(count == 2) {
                    player_two_count++;
                } else if(count == 3) {
                    player_three_count++;
                } else if(count == 4) {
                    player_four_count++;
                }
            } else if(board[i][j] == computer) {
                int count = 0;
                int k = 0;
                while(i + k < n && j + k < m && board[i + k][j + k] == computer) {
                    count++;
                    k++;
                }
                if(count == 2) {
                    computer_two_count++;
                } else if(count == 3) {
                    computer_three_count++;
                } else if(count == 4) {
                    computer_four_count++;
                }

                count = 0;
                k = 0;
                while(i + k < n && j - k >= 0 && board[i + k][j - k] == computer) {
                    count++;
                    k++;
                }
                if(count == 2) {
                    computer_two_count++;
                } else if(count == 3) {
                    computer_three_count++;
                } else if(count == 4) {
                    computer_four_count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Визначаємо оцінку для ходу
    int player_score = (n <= 5 ? player_two_count - computer_two_count : player_three_count - computer_three_count);
    int computer_score = (n <= 5 ? computer_two_count - player_two_count : computer_three_count - player_three_count);
    return computer_score - player_score;

}

int alpha_beta(int depth, int alpha, int beta, bool maximize) {
    if(depth == 0 || is_full() || is_win(player) || is_win(computer)) {
        return evaluate();
    }

    if(maximize) {
        int max_val = -INF;
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                if(board[i][j] == '.') {
                    board[i][j] = computer;
                    if(is_win(computer)) {
                        board[i][j] = '.';
                        return (n <= 5 ? 100 : 1000);
                    }
                    int val = alpha_beta(depth - 1, alpha, beta, false);
                    board[i][j] = '.';
                    max_val = max(max_val, val);
                    alpha = max(alpha, val);
                    if(beta <= alpha) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(beta <= alpha) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return max_val;
    } else {
        int min_val = INF;
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                if(board[i][j] == '.') {
                    board[i][j] = player;
                    if(is_win(player)) {
                        board[i][j] = '.';
                        return (n <= 5 ? -100 : -1000);
                    }
                    int val = alpha_beta(depth - 1, alpha, beta, true);
                    board[i][j] = '.';
                    min_val = min(min_val, val);
                    beta = min(beta, val);
                    if(beta <= alpha) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(beta <= alpha) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return min_val;
    }
}
```